# Selenium Integration Test: How to access service classes?

Tags: java, spring, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager

I'm currently trying to implement a Test where I create a User and then checking the Database if the new User is there. For that, I want to access my service class, but for some Reason the Service is always Null. I tried using Autowired, but that also didn't work.

My Testclass :

```
public class UserTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserdataService userdataService;
 
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("Selenium.WebDriverFactory#getAll")
    public void createUser(final WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException{

        List<UserdataDto> users = getAllUsers();
        UserdataDto user = users.get(users.size() - 1);
        assertEquals(user.getEmail(), "testUser@email.com");

    }

    @ResponseBody
    public List<UserdataDto> getAllUsers() {
        return userdataService.getAllUsers();
    }

}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "service.UserdataService.getAllUsers()" because "this.userdataService" is null
    at Selenium.UserTest.getAllUsers(UserTest.java:78)
    at Selenium.UserTest.createAndDeleteUser(UserTest.java:57)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `@Autowired` tag above `private UserdataService userdataService;`

Comment: Thanks for the Answer I tried it but it didn't work.
I think it has more something to to with how I use my WebDriverFactory.

Comment: That can't be, because you do a getAllUsers, that gives a null-pointer, which means that or GetAllUsers() returns null, so there is a problem in the userdataService. Or userdataService is null. You can find out where the problem is if you do  a System.out.println(userdataService); if that's null you've found the problem. Otherwise it's because there are no users.

Comment: Dit you use @Autowired with capital A

Comment: Yes I used Autowired with Capital A. And the userdataService is null, that was the problem I was asking help for I have edited the question to better shwo that.

Comment: What annotation do you use above the test class?

Comment: Im using nothing above the test class.

Comment: You should use `@Test` or `@SpringBootTest`